# Async client has different accept header than non-async client

Tags: servicestack

```
Why does the async client accept the client type along with */*
```

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Common/ServiceClient.Web/AsyncServiceClient.cs#L347

Where the regular client only accepts the client type
https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Common/ServiceClient.Web/XmlServiceClient.cs#L32

```
Also, is the best way to accept */* (or application/atom+xml, 
which is what i need) to create a new service client for non-async calls?
```